# How determine File is Open in WIndow while writing file using Flex 3/AIR File Class

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex3

I want to update a file using FLex3/AIR File class. I know how to do this , but before writing(updating) to file i want to check if current file is open in the OS or some other application is using that file or not .
please kindly help on this.

Thanks
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with AIR alone.  However, you can launch a command line app from your AIR app to get this info and return it to AIR.  You'd need a separate command line and results processor per OS though.

On Windows you can do this with [handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx).